проблема с six.moves No module named 'six.moves'
при запуске программы с терминала появляется ошибка
    from six.moves import cStringIO
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six.moves'

переустановил six, выводит:
DEPRECATION: textract 1.6.5 has a non-standard dependency specifier extract-msg<=0.29.*. pip 23.3 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to upgrade to a newer version of textract or contact the author to suggest that they release a version with a conforming dependency specifiers. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12063
Installing collected packages: six
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
textract 1.6.5 requires six~=1.12.0, but you have six 1.16.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed six-1.16.0

причём при запуске программы через pycharm никаких ошибок нет.

А вы запускаете программу в том же виртуальном окружении что и pycharm?

@andreymal, нет, у меня в проекте pycharm отдельное окружение, а запускаю через команду в powershell python main.py

А что у вас за (древняя) программа, что six понадобился?
